# Unable to access a value of a property

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my project there is a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. The custom cell's got a property of a label. While initializing a `UICollectionView` instance I also register the custom cell class with its identifier. The problem is being that the property is optional, so in theory it can be nil. I set up the property when configuring cells and it should not be nil. Even though it's assigned with an existing instance of `UILabel` I've got a runtime error - **Founded nil while unwrapping an optional value**.

The code I used for my cell:

```
class MonthCalendarCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var dateLabel: UILabel?

    func addDateLabel(label: UILabel) {
        self.dateLabel = label
        self.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

This is the initialization of a collection view:

```
override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    let calendarFlowLayout = CalendarFlowLayout()

    super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: calendarFlowLayout)

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    self.registerClass(MonthCalendarCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: self.identifier)

    // TODO: work on this
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()
}
```

Configuring a cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MonthCalendarCell

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "1"
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.highlightView(label)

    cell.addDateLabel(label)

    return cell
}
```

The problem occurs here:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MonthCalendarCell
    println(cell.dateLabel!)
}
```

I've also tried to use get/set way of accessing and initializing, but it doesn't work well.

```
class MonthCalendarCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var dateLabel: UILabel? {
        get {
            return self.dateLabel
        }

        set(label) {
            self.addSubview(label!)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd be thankful if you could explain how to set a value and how to return in that case!

And please help me figure out what's wrong with unwrapping the value, who is it nil?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're retrieving an unconfigured cell with your `dequeueReusableCell...` call. Instead you need to call `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? MonthCalendarCell {
    println(cell.dateLabel!)
}
```

Comment: Oh my God! Seems like I forgot my eyes somewhere! Thank you so much! :)